# How to download Certificate and Private Key on AWS EC2 when using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am relatively new to nodeJS.  I have a AWS Instance using EC2 and I have successfully built http based severs.

I now want a SSL based server.

I used AWS Certificate Manager to create a new certificate and I have assigned it to the Load Balancer.

Within NodeJS I know I have to load the certificate and private key before creating the server.

What I seem to be missing is how to get the certificate and private key files onto my nodeJS server so that I can load them.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

> Within NodeJS I know I have to load the certificate and private key
>   before creating the server.

Incorrect. The certificate is served by the ACM certificate Elastic Load Balancer. It does not need to be, and can't be, installed on the NodeJS server.

> What I seem to be missing is how to get the certificate and private
>   key files onto my nodeJS server so that I can load them.

You don't. That's not how ACM SSL certificates work. Once you have assigned the ACM certificate to the load balancer, and modified your DNS entries to point to the load balancer, you should be able to load your website via SSL.

Comment: Hmm, ok so maybe I am doing something wrong in nodejs.  I tried doing a createServer command      var https = require("https");     server = https.createServer(GlobalInit).listen(443);  When I run this I get an error "Missing PFX" which I believe indicates it does not know where to get the cert/key from.  Code snippets I have seen load these files and so I was trying to do the same.  If you are saying that this is not correct, could you tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The load balancer listens on port 443 and terminates the SSL connection there. It sends the request to the NodeJS server on port 80. Like I said, you don't make changes to your NodeJS app in order for this to work. Go back to the version of your NodeJS app that was working before you started messing with SSL.