# Accessing Node.js server via AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Having a problem to access my Node server via Elastic Beanstalk.

**Process of what I did:**

1. Create self-signed certificate via openssl
2. Setup elastic beanstalk environment. Set security group inbound with port 8443 and outbound to all traffics.
3. Upload to Load Balancer
4. Create new listener with port 8443. Attach SSL certificate. Disable other ports.
5. Upload server code. Attached part of the codes.

   ```
   var https = require('https');
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   // other packages ...

   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

   app.get(‘/path’, function (req, res) {

    // ignore ..

   });

   https.createServer(function (req, app) {

     // ignore ..

   }).listen(8443);
   ```

**Also tried to set in this way:**

```
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8443);
 app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Both ways do not seem work for me when I am trying to access via

```
https://xxxx-env.xxxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Based on the reference I found here ([How to download Certificate and Private Key on AWS EC2 when using NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180146/how-to-download-certificate-and-private-key-on-aws-ec2-when-using-nodejs)) I do not think I need to set certificate when I create https server.

Does that means I have to buy certificate instead of using self-signed?

Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure your 80 port is open in Inbound rules and ELB is set for all traffic coming to 80 port should be redirected to 8443

Comment: @karansharma Just make sure I understand correclty. Open 80 port for security group inbound. Add listener of 80 port for Load Balancer. After those steps, Load Balancer will redirect to 8443.

Comment: yup, that's correct

Comment: @karansharma Thanks! I eventually used this way.  1. 80 port for security group inbound. 2. 8443 for LB port and use 80 for instance port. 3. server keep listnering port 80. This should make client to LB connected via https.